# my index does not show the slider in start

Tags: slideshow

My slider is not show in the start, but when we go to other pages and return it starts working? and other pages are normal.
Also in all browser my nav menue works but in mobiles browsers is not inline. and is asking for attribute "alt" in valdity.

```
<!-- Begin DWUser_EasyRotator -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://c520866.r66.cf2.rackcdn.com/1/js/easy_rotator.min.js"></script>
      <div class="dwuserEasyRotator" style="width: 968px; height: 250px; position:relative; text-align: left;" data-erconfig="{autoplayEnabled:true, lpp:'102-105-108-101-58-47-47-47-67-58-47-85-115-101-114-115-47-72-37-50-54-77-47-68-111-99-117-109-101-110-116-115-47-69-97-115-121-82-111-116-97-116-111-114-80-114-101-118-105-101-119-47-112-114-101-118-105-101-119-95-115-119-102-115-47', wv:1, autoplayDelay:3000, autoplayStopOnInteraction:false, autoplayPauseOnHover:false}" data-ername="NMO" data-ertid="{yjk5r3ym537786896430731}">
     <div data-ertype="content" style="display: none;"><ul data-erlabel="Main Category">
    <li>
        <img class="main" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop2.jpg" /> <img class="thumb" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop2.jpg" alt="33" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="main" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop3.jpg" /> <img class="thumb" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop3.jpg" alt="44" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="main" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop4.jpg" /> <img class="thumb" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop4.jpg" alt="55" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="main" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop5.jpg" /> <img class="thumb" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop5.jpg" alt="66" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="main" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop6.jpg" /> <img class="thumb" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop6.jpg" alt="77"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="main" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop7.jpg" /> <img class="thumb" src="../images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop7.jpg" alt="88" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
     <div data-ertype="layout" data-ertemplatename="NONE" style="">         <div class="erimgMain" style="position: absolute; left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:13px;" data-erConfig="{___numTiles:3, scaleMode:'fillArea', imgType:'main', alwaysPreviousButton:true, __loopNextButton:false, __arrowButtonMode:'rollover'}">
                <div class="erimgMain_slides" style="position: absolute; left:50px; top:0; bottom:0; right:50px; text-align: left;">
                    <div class="erimgMain_slide">
                        <div class="erimgMain_img" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; width: 200px; top: 20px; bottom: 20px;"></div>
                        <div class="" style="position: absolute; left: 240px; right: 20px; top:20px; bottom: 20px; padding: 0; color: #000; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, _serif;">
                            <p class="erimgMain_title" style="padding: 0; margin: 0 0 13px 0; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px;"></p>
                            <p class="erimgMain_desc" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px;"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="erimgMain_arrowLeft" style="position:absolute; left: 10px; top: 50%; margin-top: -15px;" data-erConfig="{image:'circleSmall', image2:'circleSmall'}"></div>
                <div class="erimgMain_arrowRight" style="position:absolute; right: 10px; top: 50%; margin-top: -15px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="erdots" style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0; font-size: 10px; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, _sans; color: #FFF; position: absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;" data-erConfig="{showText:true}" align="center">
                <div class="erdots_wrap" style="wasbackground-color: #CFC; float: none;" align="left"> <!-- modify the float on this element to make left/right/none=center aligned. -->
                    <span class="erdots_btn_selected" style="padding-left: 0; width: 21px; height: 20px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 2px 0 0; cursor: default; background: url(http://easyrotator.s3.amazonaws.com/1/i/rotator/dots/export/20_14_black_65.png) top left no-repeat;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </span>
                    <span class="erdots_btn_normal" style="padding-left: 0; width: 21px; height: 20px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 2px 0 0; cursor: pointer; background: url(http://easyrotator.s3.amazonaws.com/1/i/rotator/dots/export/20_14_black_35.png) top left no-repeat;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </span>
                    <span class="erdots_btn_hover" style="padding-left: 0; width: 21px; height: 20px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 2px 0 0; cursor: pointer; background: url(http://easyrotator.s3.amazonaws.com/1/i/rotator/dots/export/20_14_black_65.png) top left no-repeat;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><div class="erabout erFixCSS3" style="color: #FFF; text-align: left; background: #000; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.93); border: 2px solid #FFF; padding: 20px; font: normal 11px/14px Verdana,_sans; width: 300px; border-radius: 10px; display:none;"> This <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/" target="_blank">jQuery slider</a> was created with the free <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/" target="_blank">EasyRotator</a> software from DWUser.com. <br />
         <br />
         Use WordPress? The free <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/wordpress/" target="_blank">EasyRotator for WordPress</a> plugin lets you create beautiful <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/wordpress/" target="_blank">WordPress sliders</a> in seconds. <br />
         <br />
         <a style="color:#FFF;" href="#" class="erabout_ok">OK</a></div>
       <noscript>
         Rotator powered by <a href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/">EasyRotator</a>, a free and easy jQuery slider builder from DWUser.com.  Please enable JavaScript to view.
        </noscript>
       <script type="text/javascript">/*Avoid IE gzip bug*/(function(b,c,d){try{if(!b[d]){b[d]="temp";var a=c.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.src="http://easyrotator.s3.amazonaws.com/1/js/nozip/easy_rotator.min.js";c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)}}catch(e){alert("EasyRotator fail; contact support.")}})(window,document,"er_$144");</script>
     </div>
   </div>
   <!-- End DWUser_EasyRotator -->
```

Thanks,

Ray

Answer (score 0):

Your image URLs are wrong: they link to a directory above the root directory. This cannot work. Place the images in the theme instead and use `get_template_directory_uri()`:

```
src="<?php 
    echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/slider/xfs_968x350_s80_mainTop2.jpg'; 
?>"
```